# Right click on title of document no longer opens finder

Tags: finder

I seem to remember that right clicking on the title of a document in an application like TextEdit, Preview, or Pages would allow you to jump to the enclosing folder in Finder.

But this no longer works on my computer. I am afraid it is because I installed Path Finder. I uninstalled path finder Following their instructions. Does anyone no how to reset this functionality?

Odd note: Right click still works for some 3rd party apps like Text Wrangler

How can I fix all of Apple's apps to Open folders in finder again?

Comment: I use command-click for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in OS X in 10.8.2

Comment: I'm still running into it in 10.8.2. It only happens intermittently, but see [TotalFinder's support forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/binaryage/topics/totalfinder_and_archive_utility_not_playing_nice) for a way to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think this relates to a bug in 10.8.2. I don't know the full extent of the bug, but it seems to break the ability to reveal a file/document in Finder from other programs, including via the title bar.

I've seen a few bug reports around relating to the 'Show in Finder' not working, or only sometimes working, due to issues with the `appleeventsd` process. For more info see this [TotalFinder Feedback](https://getsatisfaction.com/binaryage/topics/totalfinder_and_archive_utility_not_playing_nice) issue, a blog entry from [Macromates](http://blog.macromates.com/2012/apple-events-10-8-2/) and an issue on [Open Radar](http://www.openradar.me/12424662).

Answer (score 2):

All that right-clicking on a document title ever did--and what it does now, in Mountain Lion--is to reveal a navigable path of the document, which is very handy indeed. In addition, in Safari, amazingly enough, to right-click on a page title reveals the way up the site to the site root.

Answer (score 1):

1) Open Activity Monitor and search for the appleeventsd process.

2) Quit appleeventsd process (since it belongs to _eppc, use Force Quit).

3) Wait until you see it reappear with a different PID.

Now right-clicking on the title of documents should again allow you to open any of the enclosing folders.